# Python number averages using lists and keys

Tags: list, python-3.x, dictionary, key

I'm working on a Python assignment and I'm totally stuck. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. I know it's probably not as convoluted as it seems in my head...  The details are below. Thanks very much.

Implement the following three functions (you should use an appropriate looping construct to compute the averages):

allNumAvg(numList) : takes a list of numbers and returns the average of all the numbers in the list.

posNumAvg(numList) : takes a list of numbers and returns the average of all the numbers in the list that are greater than zero.

nonPosAvg(numList) : takes a list of numbers and returns the average of all the numbers in the list that are less than or equal to zero.

Write a program that asks the user to enter some numbers (positives, negatives and zeros). Your program should NOT ask the user to enter a fixed number of numbers. Also it should NOT ask for the number of numbers the user wants to enter. But rather it should ask the user to enter a few numbers and end with -9999 (a sentinel value). The user can enter the numbers in any order. Your program should NOT ask the user to enter the positive and the negative numbers separately.

Your program then should create a list with the numbers entered (make sure NOT to include the sentinel value (-9999) in this list) and output the list and a dictionary with the following Key-Value pairs (using the input list and the above functions):

Key = 'AvgPositive'  :  Value = the average of all the positive numbers

Key = 'AvgNonPos'  :  Value = the average of all the non-positive numbers

Key = 'AvgAllNum'  :  Value = the average of all the numbers

Sample run:

Enter a number (-9999 to end):  4

Enter a number (-9999 to end):  -3

Enter a number (-9999 to end): -15

Enter a number (-9999 to end):  0

Enter a number (-9999 to end):  10

Enter a number (-9999 to end):  22

Enter a number (-9999 to end):  -9999

The list of all numbers entered is:

[4, -3, -15, 0, 10, 22]

The dictionary with averages is:

{'AvgPositive': 12.0, 'AvgNonPos': -6.0, 'AvgAllNum': 3.0}

EDIT: This is what I have so far, which I did pretty quick just to have a something to work with but I can't figure out how to implement the keys/dictionary like the assignment asks. Thanks again for any help.

```
print("This program takes user-given numbers and calculates the average") 
counter = 0  
sum_of_numbers = 0 

first_question = int(input('Please enter a number. (Enter -9999 to end):')) 

while first_question != -9999 :
    ent_num = int(input('Please enter a number. (Enter -9999 to end):'))
    sum_of_numbers = sum_of_numbers + ent_num
    counter = counter + 1
    first_question = int(input('Please enter a number (Enter -9999 to end):'))

print("Your average is " + str(sum_of_numbers/counter))
```

Comment: The question seems to hint strongly that you should put these numbers in a list and the post-process the list, not do the computations in your input loop. That and a quick look at the functions that are available to operate on lists (e.g. `sum()`) should make this pretty easy... List comprehensions make it even easier...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Python programming, and programming in general!

From your code, I assume you are not entirely familiar with Python lists, dictionaries, and functions and how to use them. I'd suggest you look up tutorials for these; knowing how to use them will make your assignment much easier.

Here are some tutorials I found with some quick searches that might help:
[Dictionary Tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm),
[List Tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_lists.htm),
[Function Tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_functions.htm)

When your assignment says to make three functions, you should probably make actual functions rather than trying to fit the functionality into your loop. For example, here is a simple function that takes in a number and adds 5 to it, then returns it:

```
def addFive(number):
    return number + 5
```

To use it in your code, you would have something like this:

```
num = 6 # num is now 6
num = addFive(num) # num is now 11
```

So what you should do is create a list object containing all the numbers the user entered, and then pass that object into three separate functions - posNumAvg, nonPosAvg, allNumAvg.

Creating a dictionary of key-value pairs is pretty easy - first create the dictionary, then fill it with the appropriate values. For example, here is how I would create a dictionary like {'Hello': 'World'}

```
values = {}
values['Hello'] = 'World'
print(values) # Will print out {'Hello': 'World'}
```

So all you need to do is for each of the three values you need, assign the result of the function call to the appropriate key.

If this doesn't feel like quite enough for you to figure out this assignment, read the tutorials again and play with lists, dictionarys, and functions to try and get a feel for them. Good luck!

P.S. The append method of lists will be helpful to you. Try to figure out how to use it!